# How to measure number of XCM messages sent on a relay chain?

Tags: xcm, data-analytics

Hi trying to understand total number of XCM messages sent on a relay chain.

Should I be counting all ‘Sent’ events from the ‘xcmpallet’.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Not a direct answer to the question but I think this will be useful:

Polkaholic.io just released [this block indexer](https://polkaholic.io/xcmtransfers/polkadot) where you can monitor every XCM message sent and received from/in the relay chain. You can also explore submitted extrinsics from the XCM pallet with their instructions and path.

Note that it is the first version of this indexer tool so expect changes and improvements to be made.

**Edit**: Subscan added recently [this beautiful interface](https://polkadot.subscan.io/xcm_dashboard) to keep track of every XCM message sent between parachain-parachain and parachain-relay chain.